# Console Error for woocommerce_shared_settings deprecation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am working with WooCommerce for the first time and I am currently implementing WC filters on the shop page. The filters show up but are not functional, and the console is throwing the following errors:

> ERROR 1: `woocommerce_shared_settings` filter in Blocks is deprecated. See https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/blob/trunk/docs/contributors/block-assets.md
>
> ERROR 2: deprecated.min.js?ver=932d8bb37da8bbb396a7a3f754345e08:2 `select` control in `@wordpress/data-controls` is deprecated since version 5.7. Please use built-in `resolveSelect` control in `@wordpress/data` instead.

The errors disappear when I remove the filters.

I have located the file where the deprecated code exists. I also read the WC docs about how to fix the issue and it presented this code:

```
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\Package;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Blocks\Assets\AssetDataRegistry;
Package::container()->get( AssetDataRegistry::class )->add( $key, $value )
```

It doesn't say where to put this code, though. Where should I put it to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
Which is the file you located?
[Here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/blob/trunk/docs/contributors/block-assets.md) also says you have to add, on the "client side", this code:

```
wc.wcSettings.getSetting( 'key' );
```

Comment: In the original WooCommerce files (under plugins)

The path is wp-content > plugins > woocommerce > includes > wc-template-functions.php